# how to copy the data to the state without changing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a an array of data in a file named 'external-data.js' like this

```
``
export const mydata = [
  {
    name: "john",
    age: 20,
    man: true
  },
  {
    name: "julia",
    age: 22,
    man: false
  }
];
``
```

and then i import the data in my 'reactjs' app and i tried destructuring it like so

```
``  
import React, {component} from 'react';
import { mydata } from 'external-data.js';

class HumanApp extends Component {
  
   state = {
     myNewData: [...mydata]
   }
   
   componentDidMount() {
    this.changeData();
   }

   const changeData = () => {
     myNewData.map(item => item.name = 'boyka');
     console.log("state Data: "+myNewData[0].name); 
     console.log("original Data:"+Mydata[0].name);
   }
  
   render() {
     return (
      ....
     );
   }
 };

export default HumanApp;
``
```

and then i expected to get: " state Data: boyka" and "original Data: john" but it seems that my changeData function also changed the original array and i get "original Data: boyka"

Comment: isn't this just a typo? myData (imported) vs. MyData (used). By the way, you don't need the expansion: `[...MyData]`, just `myNewData: MyData` is fine. Also, to access it in changeData you still need to use `this.state.myNewData` (not just `myNewData`).

Answer (score 1):

```
state = {
    myNewData: [
        ...mydata.map(data => { ...data })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { mydata } from "./external-data.js";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    myNewData: [...mydata]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.changeData();
  }

  changeData = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => {
        const myNewData = { ...prevState.myNewData };
        this.state.myNewData.forEach((item) => {
          item.name = "boyka";
        });
        return {
          myNewData
        };
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.myNewData);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <div>Hii</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

You cannot mutate the state directly!! You need to change the state using [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) like the example above.